# How to get a list of consumed IAP's to show user list of in-game receipts with date?

Tags: android, google-play-services

In my game I've implemented consumption of managed items.

Recently, a parent wrote me a suggestion: **to show a list of purchases within the game so that the parent can quickly check whether it's reasonable to make another purchase.**

I suppose the use-case is that the parent wants to only make a purchase for their kid once every x weeks.

Obviously, I didn't anticipate such a feature request, hence, I didn't implement anything in firebase to track consumed managed items.

**Is there anything in the Google In-App-Billing API set to facilitate such a feature?** When I sign in to my developer console, I can see the list of purchases of all consumed items, so the data is not erased once consumed. I'm hoping that Google has an API ...

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve information about purchases that are made by a user from your app, call the getPurchases method on the In-app Billing Version 3 service. Pass the In-app Billing API version (“3”), the package name of your calling app, and the purchase type (“inapp” or "subs") into the method. Here is an example:

```
Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
```

The response Bundle contains a list of the product IDs, a list of the order details for each purchase, and the signatures for each purchase.

Look [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html) for more.